# Make a card with a background image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am new to webdevelopment and I created this in bootstrap 5: [codepen](https://codepen.io/zenunbeh/pen/ExWveGO)

However, instead having the icons in the front I wanted that an images is showing. Then when the card is flipped it should, the content should stay, as demonstrated in codepen. Can anyone help me to realize my request?

This is the CSS code:

```css
.services .icon-box {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #e2eefd;
  padding: 80px 20px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
}

.services .icon-box .icon {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  background: #f1f6fe;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #deebfd;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
}

.services .icon-box .icon i {
  color: #3b8af2;
  font-size: 28px;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
}

.services .icon-box h4 {
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.services .icon-box h4 a {
  color: #222222;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
}

.services .icon-box p {
  line-height: 24px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.services .icon-box:hover {
  border-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0 25px 0 rgba(16, 110, 234, 0.1);
}

.services .icon-box:hover h4 a, .services .icon-box:hover .icon i {
  color: #106eea;
}

.services .icon-box:hover .icon {
  border-color: #106eea;
}

.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 337px;
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-back {
  color: black;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);

}

.flip-card:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

This is the HTML code:

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i|Roboto:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i|Poppins:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="services" class="services">
  <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">

    <div class="section-title">
      <h2>Lorem</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam nec aliquam metus, ac vehicula nibh. Nunc scelerisque tellus eu ullamcorper fermentum. Nam non condimentum lectus, vel dapibus leo. Integer elementum, elit id lacinia tempus, nisl augue
        accumsan est, nec lacinia libero eros non nulla. Pellentesque viverra eget lorem nec pellentesque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. .</p>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch flip-card" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="100">
        <div class="icon-box flip-card-inner" style="text-align: center;">
          <div class="flip-card-front">
            <div class="icon"><i class="bx bxl-dribbble"></i></div>
            <h4><a href="">Lorem</a></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="flip-card-back">
            <p>Modi nostrum vel laborum. Porro fugit error sit minus sapiente sit aspernatur.Modi nostrum vel laborum. Porro fugit error sit minus sapiente sit aspernatur.Modi nostrum vel laborum. Porro fugit error sit minus sapiente sit aspernatur.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mt-4 mt-md-0" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="200">
        <div class="icon-box">
          <div class="icon"><i class="bx bx-file"></i></div>
          <h4><a href="">Lorem</a></h4>
          <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mt-4 mt-lg-0" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="300">
        <div class="icon-box">
          <div class="icon"><i class="bx bx-tachometer"></i></div>
          <h4><a href="">Lorem</a></h4>
          <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mt-4" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="100">
        <div class="icon-box">
          <div class="icon"><i class="bx bx-world"></i></div>
          <h4><a href="">Lorem</a></h4>
          <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mt-4" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="200">
        <div class="icon-box">
          <div class="icon"><i class="bx bx-slideshow"></i></div>
          <h4><a href="">Lorem</a></h4>
          <p>Quis consequatur saepe eligendi voluptatem consequatur dolor consequuntur</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mt-4" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="300">
        <div class="icon-box">
          <div class="icon"><i class="bx bx-arch"></i></div>
          <h4><a href="">Lorem</a></h4>
          <p>Modi nostrum vel laborum. Porro fugit error sit minus sapiente sit aspernatur</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Here is the codepen link: https://codepen.io/zenunbeh/pen/ExWveGO

Comment: Hello @James, take a look at this class: ` .flip-card-inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcStJKy43H8Cr_3d5525o4tYLgsE0cB65hHUvg&usqp=CAU");
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

feel free to check out this example, i have updated your **CSS-file** at **line 69** to add your CSS required rules:

```css
.services .icon-box {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #e2eefd;
  padding: 80px 20px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
}

.services .icon-box .icon {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  background: #f1f6fe;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #deebfd;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
}

.services .icon-box .icon i {
  color: #3b8af2;
  font-size: 28px;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
}

.services .icon-box h4 {
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.services .icon-box h4 a {
  color: #222222;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
}

.services .icon-box p {
  line-height: 24px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.services .icon-box:hover {
  border-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0 25px 0 rgba(16, 110, 234, 0.1);
}

.services .icon-box:hover h4 a, .services .icon-box:hover .icon i {
  color: #106eea;
}

.services .icon-box:hover .icon {
  border-color: #106eea;
}

.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
 
  height: 337px;
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-inner:not(:hover){
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcStJKy43H8Cr_3d5525o4tYLgsE0cB65hHUvg&usqp=CAU");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-x: center;
}

.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-back {
  color: black;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);

}

.flip-card:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i|Roboto:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i|Poppins:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="services" class="services">
      <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">

        <div class="section-title">
          <h2>Lorem</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam nec aliquam metus, ac vehicula nibh. Nunc scelerisque tellus eu ullamcorper fermentum. Nam non condimentum lectus, vel dapibus leo. Integer elementum, elit id lacinia tempus, nisl augue accumsan est, nec lacinia libero eros non nulla. Pellentesque viverra eget lorem nec pellentesque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. .</p>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch flip-card" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="100">
            <div class="icon-box flip-card-inner" style="text-align: center;">
              <div class="flip-card-front">
                <div class="icon"><i class="bx bxl-dribbble"></i></div>
                <h4><a href="">Lorem</a></h4>
              </div>
              <div class="flip-card-back">
                <p>Modi nostrum vel laborum. Porro fugit error sit minus sapiente sit aspernatur.Modi nostrum vel laborum. Porro fugit error sit minus sapiente sit aspernatur.Modi nostrum vel laborum. Porro fugit error sit minus sapiente sit aspernatur.</p>
              </div>   
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mt-4 mt-md-0" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="200">
            <div class="icon-box">
              <div class="icon"><i class="bx bx-file"></i></div>
              <h4><a href="">Lorem</a></h4>
              <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mt-4 mt-lg-0" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="300">
            <div class="icon-box">
              <div class="icon"><i class="bx bx-tachometer"></i></div>
              <h4><a href="">Lorem</a></h4>
              <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mt-4" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="100">
            <div class="icon-box">
              <div class="icon"><i class="bx bx-world"></i></div>
              <h4><a href="">Lorem</a></h4>
              <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mt-4" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="200">
            <div class="icon-box">
              <div class="icon"><i class="bx bx-slideshow"></i></div>
              <h4><a href="">Lorem</a></h4>
              <p>Quis consequatur saepe eligendi voluptatem consequatur dolor consequuntur</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mt-4" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="300">
            <div class="icon-box">
              <div class="icon"><i class="bx bx-arch"></i></div>
              <h4><a href="">Lorem</a></h4>
              <p>Modi nostrum vel laborum. Porro fugit error sit minus sapiente sit aspernatur</p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </section>
```

Feel free to upvote the answer, if it,s what you expected.

Comment: That helps! Thank you! But when it flipped it should show the white background with the content. Can you assist me there too?

Comment: Your mean the image should not be displayed at full opacity ?

Comment: If you look at my codepen, when I hover over it the "flip-card-back" should be with a white background and not showing the image again

Comment: okay you mean only on hover, it should be displayed right ?

Comment: Yes. So the flip-card-front should display the image and when flipping the card, it shouldn't show up the image

Comment: Answer got updated, make sure to mark it as answer if it,s now all good!

Comment: can you explain me where did you make changes in the code?

Comment: I added some specification to the mentioned class as you wished, **line 69** only CSS class `.flip-card-inner:not(:hover)`.

Comment: Don,t forget to upvote comments and answer, if it really helped you out 100%. Later i mean :). Have a nice day!

Comment: it's not 100% but it really helped! Thank you